# Split on backslash merges split elements

Tags: javascript, split, backslash

I try to split a string on a backslash. However, the `split` method doesn't return 2 elements but just 1 without the backslash:

```
'0.023750\0.023746'.split("\\")
> ["0.023750.023746"]
```

Comment: ok the issues seems to be that \0 is interpreted as the 'null' character before the split is actually invoked

Comment: You need to escape your `\ ` ex `'0.023750\\0.023746'.split("\\")`

Comment: Your input string does not contain a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` method doesn't work, because "\0" is special symbol as "\n" or "\r" that means NULL. So that why your string is interpreted incorrectly. Solution is: write before your string symbol 'r'. It will say to interpreter to ignore special symbols.

```
r'0.023750\0.023746'.split("\\")
> ['0.023750', '0.023746']
```

Comment: hmm doesn't seem too work: VM174:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string.
I guess you are talking in Python - JS equivalent is String.raw FYI. Thanks